# Injecting css file into head of html file generated using HtmlWebpackPlugin

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, babeljs, html-webpack-plugin

I have configured the [babel-css-in-js plugin](https://github.com/martinandert/babel-plugin-css-in-js) to build a css file into `./app/bundle.css` when webpack runs the `babel-loader`. I need to inject this file into an HTML file generated by `html-webpack-plugin`. I have tried loading it through the `css-loader` like:

```
import './bundle.css';

const styles = cssInJs({
  red: {
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
});

const redClass = cx(styles.red);

function HelloWorld() {
  return (<h2 className={redClass}><LoremIpsum /></h2>);
}
```

but I get the error:

```
client?cb1f:75 ENOTSUP: operation not supported on socket,  
uv_interface_addresses
 @ ./app/index.js 17:0-23

 ./bundle.css not found
```

This is my `.babelrc`:

```
["css-in-js", {
 "vendorPrefixes":true,
 "mediaMap":{
   "phone": "media only screen and (max-width: 768px)",
   "tablet":"media only screen and (max-width: 992px)",
   "desktop":"media only screen and (max-width: 1200px)"
 },
 "identifier": "cssInJs",
 "transformOptions":{
 "presets":["env"]
 },
   "bundleFile": "./app/bundle.css"
 }
]
```

The html-webpack-plugin uses the `html-webpack-template` for its configuration like this:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  inject: false,
  mobile: true,
  appMountId: 'root',
  template,
}),
```

Are there any other mechanisms that I can use to inject the `css file` into the head of the generated template?

The source of the project is on [github](https://github.com/vamsiampolu/css-in-js-test/)

Comment: you can take a look at or just use glamor https://github.com/threepointone/glamor

Comment: @skav what does glamor do to my inline styles, rendering in a `style tag` or as a `seperate file`? does it auto-inject the file or would I be required to use the `ExtractTextPlugin`

Comment: I used `react-helmet` to inject the `link` into head. Looking for a better solution though

Comment: glamor creates a style tag in the head of the current page

Comment: @skav, I will try that, seems to support server side rendering as well. how is it different from `khan academy/aphrodite`

Comment: its detailed - i recommend doing the homework yourself so you can find the one that suits your needs the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have injected the external stylesheet into the generated html page using [`react-helmet`](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet). First, I removed the `css-loader` from the `webpack.config.js` and the `import ./bundle.css` from my module. I edited my `.babelrc` to change the `bundlePath` of the `css` to the `build` directory.

Then I added:

```
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

const cssLink = {
  rel: 'stylesheet',
  type: 'text/css',
  href: './bundle.css',
};
```

I added the following to my root component:

```
 <Helmet link={[cssLink]} />
```

The component now looks like:

```
function HelloWorld() {
  return (<h2 className={redClass}>
    <Helmet link={[cssLink]} />
    <LoremIpsum />
  </h2>);
}
```

Take a look at the [.babelrc](https://github.com/vamsiampolu/css-in-js-test/blob/9c1c1696be04553b5a13c867686141ca555ce6ea/.babelrc) and [index.js](https://github.com/vamsiampolu/css-in-js-test/blob/9c1c1696be04553b5a13c867686141ca555ce6ea/app/index.js)